Unresponsive website buttons on different Macs
There are buttons on some internal websites (can't provide an explicit link). Clicking most of them just gives no response at all in any browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge) on all my different Macs. The buttons seem to be javascript buttons as mouse-over displays 'javascript:void(0);'. And I don't have any specific antivirus software installed.
Looks a bit like this old post, but the solution there doesn't apply.
These websites and buttons are being heavily used by many people (many are Windows). I happened to be able to confirm that some Apple Silicon user can use it without any problem. But not for me.
I finally noticed the following option in Safari.

When we browse site A, there is an option Safari --> Settings for "address of site A" --> enable content blockers.

Unticking it helps my M2 Air to work.
But this does not help for another Mac Studio or Intel iMac at all.
And another guy's M-chip Air even works well with it ticked...
I'm using the latest macOS and browsers.
Any possible fix or direction? Thanks.

Have you enabled Javascript in each of those web browsers/macs? In Safari go to Settings>Privacy and tick Enable Javascript. For Firefox, see this support article: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages. For Chrome go to Settings>Privacy and Security>Site Settings>Content>Javascript and ensure the default behaviour is enabled for Javascript. For other web browsers (Edge, Brave, Opera, etc), just search their settings pages or support page for the particular web browser on how to enable Javascript

Note depending on how strict you've set the privacy protections/safe browsing/enhanced tracking protection for each web browser, it may still block Javascript even if Javascript is enabled by default. In this case try lowering the privacy protection/safe browsing/enhanced tracking protection to standard OR whitelist just that website to have no protection. If you have Javascript blocked by default, you may also try just whitelisting the particular websites only to allow for Javascript and keep javascript blocked for all other websites (though I don't think you can whitelist in Safari?)

@AVelj Thank you for the explanation. Javascript is always enabled. Tried privacy/tracking options and clearing cookies/cache data in Safari and firefox, still no effect.

No problems. The only other thing I can think of is some experimental feature is blocking Javascript? In Safari you can enable the Develop menu under Safari Settings>Advanced and enable Show Develop menu in menu bar and then it should show you the Develop menu option in the menu bar. Try reading through the various options in experimental features there. Also the develop menu has other options including Javascript console, allow javascript for Apple events, disable javascript, etc. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.
